# Azure ML: What is the confidence level setting for Azure ML prediction? And can it be tuned?

Tags: statistics, prediction, azure-machine-learning-service

I have built a couple of models on some data using Boosted Trees and hyperparameter setting.

However, when I am trying to use the models for prediction, it doesn't give prediction results for a lot of them, some ranging to 75% of the data. I am guessing this has got something to do with the model; and for some reason it does not predict for some results, which makes me guess it has got something to do with the confidence threshold of the prediction.

Please correct me, if I am wrong somewhere.

Guide me, in any case.

Comment: It depends on the data....what kind of predictive model are you trying to build...are you using a public dataset?

Comment: Do you mean it's not predicting anything at all? If that's the case, then it probably has something to do with the data that you're trying to predict on. For example, it has missing values and Azure ML doesn't handle that well, or the data you are trying to predict on is different than the data you trained the model on.

Comment: @Hackerman: I am trying to build a Boosted Decision Tree Regression in Azure ML.... And no it is a private dataset...

Comment: @Tchotchke: Yes, it isn't showing any prediction result.... Also, the test data is a different set from the train set..... Addiotionally, we have done analysis on missing data, and removed many missing values... There are some missing values, I won't deny that... But then, there has been some predictions with the missing data, so it is more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a lot of deliberate attempts, the only thing which worked is imputation. As suggested in the question comments, the issue was with the missing data, and as soon as we handled the missing data case, Azure ML worked and predicted results for all the records.